# showing kwic in scrapy item

Tags: python, scrapy

Good afternoon all,

I am trying to write a spider that will give me results with keywords in context. I've managed to find this link: [python truncate text around keyword](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4319473/python-truncate-text-around-keyword)
which explains a way to do this, I've moulded it a little to suite my needs but am now no longer getting any scraped data in my database. (the only thing that's changed is I've added the code to grab the kwic as one of my Items).

My Spider:

```
# tabbing in python is apparently VERY important so be aware and make sure 
# things that should line up do so

# import the CrawlSpider Class, along with it's Rules, (this lets us recursively
# crawl pages)

from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule

#import the link extractor, this extracts links from pages

from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors import LinkExtractor

# import our items as defined in items.py

from basic.items import BasicItem

# import re which allows us to compare strings

import re

# create a new Spider with the CrawlSpider Class

class BasicSpiderSpider(CrawlSpider):

    # Name of the spider, this is used to run it, (i.e Scrapy Crawl basic_spider)

    name = "basic_spider"

    # domains that the spider is allowed to crawl over

    allowed_domains = ["news24.com"]

    # where to start crawling from

    start_urls = [
        'http://www.news24.com/SouthAfrica/News/Six-things-to-know-about-the-illegal-mining-boom-20140626',
    ]

    # Rules for the link extractor, (i.e where it's allowed to look for links, 
    # what to do once it's found them, and whether it's allowed to follow them

    rules = (Rule (LinkExtractor(), callback="parse_items", follow= True),
    )

   # defining the callback function

    def parse_items(self, response):

        # defines the Top level XPath where all of our information can be found, needs to be
        # as specific as possible to avoid duplicates

        for title in response.xpath('//*[@id="aspnetForm"]'):

            # List of keywords to search through.

            key = re.compile("joburg|durban|children", re.IGNORECASE)

            # extracting the data to compare with the keywords, this is for the 
            # headlines, the join converts it from a list type to a string type

            headlist = title.xpath('//*[@id="article_special"]//h1/text()').extract()
            head = ''.join(headlist)

            # and this is for the article.

            artlist = title.xpath('//*[@id="article-body"]//text()').extract()
            art = ''.join(artlist)

            # if any keywords are found in the headline:

            if key.search(head):

                    # define the top level xpath again as python won't look outside 
                    # it's current fuction

                    for thing in response.xpath('//*[@id="aspnetForm"]'):

    # using this because i'm wanting to show the context of returned articles, found this here:
    # https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4319473/python-truncate-text-around-keyword

                        def find_with_context(haystack, needle, context_length, escape=True):
                            if escape:
                                needle = re.escape(needle)
                            return re.findall(r'\b(.{,%d})\b(%s)\b(.{,%d})\b' % (context_length, needle, context_length), haystack)


                        # fills the items defined in items.py with relevant data

                        item = BasicItem()
                        item['Headline'] = thing.xpath('//*[@id="article_special"]//h1/text()').extract()

                        #calls find_with_context

                        item["Article"] = find_with_context("joburg|durban|children", (art), 50)
    #                    item["Article"] = thing.xpath('//*[@id="article-body"]//text()').extract
                        item["Date"] = thing.xpath('//*[@id="spnDate"]/text()').extract()
                        item["Link"] = response.url

                        # I found that even with being careful about my XPaths I
                        # still got empty fields and lines, the below fixes that

                        if item['Headline']:
                            if item["Article"]:
                                if item["Date"]:
                                    yield item

            # if the headline item doesn't match, check the article item.

            elif key.search(art):
                #if last_crawled > response.xpath('//*[@id="spnDate"]/text()').extract():
                    for thing in response.xpath('//*[@id="aspnetForm"]'):

    # using this because i'm wanting to show the context of returned articles, found this here:
    # https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4319473/python-truncate-text-around-keyword                        

                        def find_with_context(haystack, needle, context_length, escape=True):
                            if escape:
                                needle = re.escape(needle)
                            return re.findall(r'\b(.{,%d})\b(%s)\b(.{,%d})\b' % (context_length, needle, context_length), haystack)


                        item = BasicItem()
                        item['Headline'] = thing.xpath('//*[@id="article_special"]//h1/text()').extract()
                        #item["Article"] = thing.xpath('//*[@id="article-body"]/p[1]/text()').extract()
                        item["Article"] = find_with_context("joburg|durban|children", (art), 50)
                        item["Date"] = thing.xpath('//*[@id="spnDate"]/text()').extract()
                        item["Link"] = response.url

                        if item['Headline']:
                            if item["Article"]:
                                if item["Date"]:
                                    yield item
```

My Log File can be downloaded here: http://1drv.ms/1y0umXn

It looks as if it's no longer recognising the page: http://www.news24.com/SouthAfrica/News/Gunshots-screaming-in-Manenberg-overnight-20150407

which does match the search criteria.

any help would be greatly appreciated

Kind regards,
Grant

Answer (score 0):

By looking at the logs, I can see that the request for that URL has been filtered out:

> 2015-04-07 12:26:17+0200 [basic_spider] DEBUG: **Ignoring link (depth >
>   1)**:
>   http://www.news24.com/SouthAfrica/News/Gunshots-screaming-in-Manenberg-overnight-20150407

The reason is because of its depth, which is filtering out many other requests. Maybe all of them that are not filtered as off-site.

From the beginning of the log we can see:

> 2015-04-07 12:26:15+0200 [scrapy] INFO: Overridden settings:
>   {'NEWSPIDER_MODULE': 'basic.spiders', **'DEPTH_LIMIT': 1**,
>   'SPIDER_MODULES': ['basic.spiders'], 'BOT_NAME': 'basic', 'LOG_FILE':
>   'log.log', 'DOWNLOAD_DELAY': 0.25}

which means you have set `'DEPTH_LIMIT': 1`. Try to remove this setting, or set it to a higher value to see if you achieve your desired results.

Comment: Thanks Lawrence, but if you look further down it does show that it successfully crawls the page: `2015-04-07 12:26:28+0200 [basic_spider] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://www.news24.com/SouthAfrica/News/Gunshots-screaming-in-Manenberg-overnight‌​-20150407> (referer: http://www.news24.com/SouthAfrica/News/Six-things-to-know-about-the-illegal-mini‌​ng-boom-20140626)`

Comment: Your code doesn't seem optimal, it might even be wrong. For example, you are trying to iterate through `'//*[@id="aspnetForm"]'` which is obviously always a single element. Also, you are then matching on the `title.xpath` selector, but using '//*' with id, which still matches the whole tree, and not starting from the `title`. You should clean those up a bit. Also, put a log statement as the first line in the `parse_items` to make sure it is called: `self.log('parse_items is called')`. After that, paste the output again.

Comment: Hi Lawrence,

I made the changes you suggested and get the following relevant output:

`2015-04-14 18:46:44+0200 [basic_spider] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://traveller24.news24.com/MyTravels> (referer: http://www.news24.com/SouthAfrica/News/Six-things-to-know-about-the-illegal-mining-boom-20140626)
2015-04-14 18:46:44+0200 [basic_spider] DEBUG: parse_items is called`

I have added the log statement as suggested:

`  def parse_items(self, response):
        self.log('parse_items is called')`

Comment: I'm not sure what the problem is now, the logs have no errors. What do you expect to see?